In SwiftUI, how to determine when PhaseAnimator completed animation
I'd like to get notified when the PhaseAnimator has completed animating the entire phase cycle.

You could use an .onChange handler to detect when the value passed to the closure goes back to the first value:
PhaseAnimator(Array(0...4)) { val in
    Circle()
        .fill(.blue)
        .frame(width: 50)
        .offset(x: CGFloat(val - 2) * 50)
        .onChange(of: val) { oldVal, newVal in
            if newVal == 0 {
                print("reset")
            }
        }
} animation: { val in
    .spring(duration: 1)
}

This works with a trigger too:
@State private var trigger = false

VStack(spacing: 100) {
    Button("Go") { trigger.toggle() }
    PhaseAnimator(Array(0...4), trigger: trigger) { val in
        // ...as above
    }
}


Perfect, thanks for the help!
